# How to efficiently find the n-th set bit?

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bmi

For code related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39623081/417501), I need to compute the following as fast as possible:

> Given a 32 bit integer *i*, compute the position of the *n*-th least significant set bit. Both *n* and the result should be 0-indexed.

For example, given the number *i* = 11010110101<sub>2</sub> and *n* = 4, the desired number is 7 as the fourth set bit is at position 7: 110**1**0110101.

Using the `pdep` instruction from the BMI2 instruction set extension for x86 and the commonly available `__builtin_ctz()` intrinsic function, this can be computed easily:

```
j = _pdep_u32(1 << n, i);
return (__builtin_ctz(j));
```

However, many computers do not have the `pdep` instruction (and it's slow on AMD CPUs that do have it), rendering this approach non-portable. You can also compute such bit positions without `pdep` like this:

```
j = i;
for (k = 0; k < n; k++)
    j &= j - 1;

return (__builtin_ctz(j));
```

However, this is pretty slow.

I am targeting computers that provide at least `__builtin_popcount()` and `__builtin_ctz()`. How can I find such bit positions faster?